# Need to click text entering area before enter text successfully in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need to entering text in a text entering area. my command is:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"{self.plateId_input}").send_keys(plateId)
```

but I have found out issue this command does not work. I have to issue the same command twice. The first time is to click the text area, so the area is ready then issue the command and the text is entered successfully. My question is is there other way to perform this task? issue the command twice does not seems like a good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.plateId_input)
element.click()
element.send_keys(plateId)
```